# how to redirect the page but not change browser's url?

Tags: html, url, redirect, web

in my project  i  gave people a restful link,the link would redirect to a page with a lot of params ,i hope people to copy and share the short address instead of the long one.

i use redirect to do it but when the page redirecting, the url on the web browser also change, is there a way to avoid this?

i give a try to use iframe to build an inner page,that seems works,at least on ie10,newest fireforx and chrome

```
<html><body style="margin:0;padding:0"><iframe src="http://xxxxxx" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe></body></html>
```

but it didn't work on some page for example 'www.google.com',and it is said it used x-frame options, but that's the case i didn't need to worry,2 domains both owned by the project. so would that be a solved problem?

Comment: Display the content right at the short URL?! Don't even have a long URL?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. X-Frame option is set if the website doesn't want u to run it in a frame on another domain. Its safe if you want to only run it on your sites. The sites must not have this header or the browser won't allow it to be loaded